# What will the LLVM compiler project bring to the table?

Tags: llvm

I have heard a lot about LLVM and I was wondering what improvements it will bring to the table.

Comment: Did you already check out the web page?

Answer (score 4):

LLVM is a newer compiler back-end.  It is currently reported to compile faster than gcc, and do more optimizations across/between source files (depends on the exact nature of the source being benchmarked, of course).  LLVM also clearly defines a high-level interface between the compiler front-end and back-end, possibly making it more portable for language research and JIT enbedding, etc.

But one important possible "improvement" may be that a few corporations that are adverse to contributing to a GPL'd code base (for whatever reasons) may contribute new compiler optimizations and back-end code to LLVM instead (since it is open source, but not GPL).

Comment: JIT compilation is pretty awesome, there are already projects to build interpreters for traditionally compiled languages such as C.